# Adding the values of multiple duplicated rows in python and creating another column

Tags: python, pandas, duplicates

I have file which have several columns. However, some rows are duplicated in Column1 with corresponding value in Column2.

It looks like this:

```
COL1   COL2
AB      5
AB      5
AA      2 
AC      3
AD      8
AD      4
```

I want to create Column3 and have it like this:

```
COL3
AB      10
AA      2 
AC      3
AD      12
```

My code is like this:

```
df['COL3'] = df.groupby(['COL2', 'COL1']).transform('sum')
```

my error is:

```
ValueError: Cannot set a DataFrame with multiple columns to the single column Final Approved Ref
```

Comment: So what's the issue? Please provide a reproduceable error and example.

Comment: @Jordan i edited it and posted the error. thank you.

Comment: The error looks to come from the .transform('sum'), where the returned DataFrame has a different length than self.

Comment: Hi @Jordan. I figured it out. I used : df = df.groupby(['COL1)'], as_index=False)['COL2'].sum()